# SQL datediff from different columns

Tags: sql, datediff

I have a table that has a date of action (let's call it X) either in a field or another (depending on another variable), the problem is that I need to get the date of when 'X' happened, so I need a new column that has the value of column1 or column2, depending on where the date is.

I am super green with this, so I've been trying with different things and now with CASE.

I got the below, but all the values I am getting in the new column "DATE_X_FINAL" all values NULL.

Even though I need a new column, I am trying with select now just to see if I can get it working.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT [Date_X], [Date_X2], 
       CASE 
       WHEN [Date_X] = NULL THEN [Date_X2]
       END as DATE_X_FINAL
    FROM [DATABASE.TABLE]
```

Result:

```
[Date_X]    [Date_X2]   DATE_X_FINAL
2020-12-23   NULL       NULL
2019-02-05   NULL       NULL
2019-02-13   NULL       NULL
2019-02-12   NULL       NULL
2019-02-06   NULL       NULL
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products have their own functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In SQL null is not equal (=) to anything—not even to another null.](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from)

You test for null comparison by using [IS NULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp).

There is a built in convenience function to do this in standard (ANSI) SQL - [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp). ("The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value in a list.")

```
SELECT Date_X, Date_X2
     , COALESCE(Date_X, Date_X2) AS 'DATE_X_FINAL' 
FROM DATABASE.TABLE
```

Comment: Alan, you know you are a rock star, right?
This absolutely and elegantly solved my problem.